# How to make global preprocessor definitions in a single place without having lots of warnings?

Tags: c#, global, definition, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I want a way to have "global preprocessor definitions" such that I can change a single value before compilation to add or remove functionality of my program. Currently I have a "global script" (called God.cs) with consts such as:

```
public const bool PRINT_RUN_VALUES = true;
public const bool DEBUG_MOVEMENT = false;
public const bool DOUBLE_SPEED = false;
```

With all relevant scripts using these values, for example:

in script 1:

```
if (God.PRINT_RUN_VALUES) {
   float averageDist = /* calculate values */
   print("Script1: averageDist = " + averageDist);
}
```

in script 2:

```
if (God.PRINT_RUN_VALUES) {
   print("Script2: radius = " + radius);
   print("Script2: time = " + time);
}
```

The problem with this method is that I get tons of

> CS0162: Unreachable code detected

warnings. I can turn off these warnings using:

```
#pragma warning disable 0162
#pragma warning disable 0429
```

But I don't want to do that because these warnings can be useful in cases that don't involve these values from God.cs. An alternative might be to use classical preprocessor definitions such as:

```
#define PRINT_RUN_VALUES
...
#if (PRINT_RUN_VALUES)
   float averageDist = /* calculate values */
   print("Script1: averageDist = " + averageDist);
#endif
```

However as far as I know that would require me to add '#define PRINT_RUN_VALUES' at the start of each .cs file, which would become a nightmare when I want to quickly turn off or on these global statements. I want all of these global definitions is a single place so that I can quickly turn them off and on.

How can I define some preprocessor thing such that it isn't included in each script? I know that there are proprocessor definitions that meet this criteria, such as definitions to check what operating system is compiling the software. Or is there another way around this?

Comment: You can set these in the project properties, this is how DEBUG is defined.

Comment: So you don't really understand the warning and how this very bad practice will get into trouble.  What is it that you *really* want to know?  Do you want to know the inconvenient truth or do you prefer to not be reminded about what you don't know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set these in the project properties, for example this is how the `DEBUG` symbol is defined. Right click on your project, select *Properties* and enter your custom csymbols in the box labelled *Conditional compilation symbols*:

[image: Project properties]

Now in my code I can do this:

```
#if CHEESE
    public string CheeseName = "Gouda";
#endif
```

Note that these symbols are defined as part of the configuration. This means you can define different symbols for release versus a debug or UAT environment for example.

Comment: In case of multiple symbols, add them with whitespaces or semi-colons separating them.